# TBB_tbb_LIBRARY_DEBUG-NOT FOUND

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, tbb

In one of the codes, during the process of implementation, I do

```
cmake..
```

But I get the error:

```
username@ubuntu:~/folder/build$ cmake ..
FINALLL TBB_LIBRARIES = 'optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so;debug;TBB_tbb_LIBRARY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND'
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
TBB_tbb_LIBRARY_DEBUG (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "DSKCFcpp" in directory /home/srishti/realtimeKCF

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/username/realtimeKCF/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

[This](https://cmake-basis.github.io/apidoc/latest/FindTBB_8cmake_source.html) tells me that (Line 29) TBB is considered to be not found when at least one required library or its include path is missing. When no TBB_FIND_COMPONENTS are specified, only the threading library "tbb" is required.

Additionally, I don't see BB_tbb_LIBRARY_DEBUG (ADVANCED) like in the following path:

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

I'm unable to figure out the solution

Comment: Could you, please, tell how TBB is imported into your project?
Currently, an officially supported binary package integration with CMake is described on [this page](https://github.com/01org/tbb/tree/tbb_2018/cmake#binary-package-integration)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem. The path of the TBB was to be changed in the CMake file. The instruction as to what should be the format are given in the same file.

Thanks.